# what's meaning of function predict's returned value in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, predict

I use function `predict` in opencv to classify my gestures.

```
svm.load("train.xml");
float ret = svm.predict(mat);//mat is my feature vector
```

I defined 5 labels `(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)`, but in fact the value of ret are `(0.521220207,-0.247173533,-0.127723947······)`

So I am confused about it. As Opencv official document, the function returns a class label (classification) in my case.

update: I don't still know why to appear this result. But I choose new features to train models and the return value of predict function is what I defined during train phase (e.g. 1 or 2 or 3 or etc).

Comment: my guess: return value is a quality/confidence measure for each class. maybe they  go from 1.0 = best to -1.0 = worst. but maybe someone else knows for a fact.

Comment: please use *integer* labels for classification. (else it thinks, you want  regression)

Answer (score 0):

During the training of an SVM you assign a label to each class of training data.

When you classify a sample the returned result will match up with one of these labels telling you which class the sample is predicted to fall into.

There's some more documentation here which might help:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

Answer (score 0):

With Support Vector Machines (SVM) you have a training function and a prediction one. The training function is to train your data and save those informations on an xml file (it facilitates the prediction process in case you use a huge number of training data and you must do the prediction function in another project).

**Example :** 20 images per class in your case : 20*5=100 training images,each image is associated with a label of its appropriate class and all these informations are stocked in train.xml)

For the prediction function , it tells you what's label to assign to your test image according to your training DATA (the hole work you did in training process). Your prediction results might be good and might be bad , it's all about your training data I think.

If you want try to calculate the error rate for your classifier to see how much it can give good results or bad ones.